# Stylus not parsing comments correctly?

Tags: css, stylus

I have the following css file:

```
/*!
 * http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
 * v2.0 | 20110126
 * License: none (public domain)
 */
...
```

However when I try to parse it, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:502
              throw err;
                    ^
TypeError: reset.styl:2
   1| /*!
 > 2|  * http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   3|  * v2.0 | 20110126
   4|  * License: none (public domain)
   5|  */

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I have noticed stylus have issue with other blocked comment too (those I just remove to get through the issues but now I need to figure out what is going on).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/comments.html

Comment: Your syntax is fine.  Your bug is elsewhere. How are you invoking the stylus compiler?

Comment: @Alex Wanye: stylus reset.styl : from command like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my editor was creating .styl files as something other than text so I updated the file type association for the application and everything seem good now.

Comment: Accept your answer, so this question wouldn't show in the list of unanswered.